# Google SQL replica need to upload views procedures and functions

Tags: mysql, function, google-cloud-sql, procedure, readonly

I have the following scenario. I have a MySQL Server on-premises and one replica instance on Google SQL. This replica sincronizes the MySQL Server master on-premises data (a typical scenario).

The problem is the following. I have functions, procedures and views on the MySQL Server on-premises and I need this functions, procedures and views. The data import to Cloud SQL must not contain functions, procedures and views and I need it! Also I can't import these manually because the Cloud SQL database is on read-only mode.

Is there any option to import it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this scenario corresponds to an [*external master configuration*](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external) (with 2nd Generation instances), then indeed, [triggers, views, or stored procedures must be excluded from any data dump file](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing).

However, you can have these components replicated in a replica during the replication process itself, provided that the users specified in `DEFINER` statements are already created in the replica.

Both `DEFINER` statements and user creation on the replica are required, as users are not replicated from the master, and that [SUPER privileges are not supported](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users).

Once these users are created in the replica, simply [restart the replica instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance#restart), and [proceed with a new replication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/manage-replicas).

There are some limitations opting for Cloud SQL, however this solution provides all the benefits of a fully managed back-end. If this wouldn't work for you, you might as well opt for [managing an independent SQL server on a Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/sql-server/creating-sql-server-instances).

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by 'proceed with a new replication'? Do you mean I should do a dump of master, but this time with the views, triggers, etc and then somehow use that dump to sync with the existing read-only replica? If so how does one do this?